# Users do not receive auto-update with multiple apk

Tags: android, google-play, auto-update, multiple-apk

I submitted an update with Multiple APK, in order to support multiple API Level and reduce APK size. Only few user updated and it seems that Auto-update doesn't work anymore (users has to manually update the app).

The build number is greater than the previous Single-APK.

Doesn't anyone has experience with Multiple APK? How can I turn on Auto-update?
Thanks

**UPDATE:**
I uploaded a new Single-APK with increased build number, and users got the app through auto-update, I can see my adoption rate about 30% about 24h after submitting.
But that still not fix the initial issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, it wasn't because the APK, an additional permission has been added, and so, users have to manually update.